# How to create a custom thread-safe IList<T>?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, locking

I have a question about the `lock` operator:

For example, I have a custom thread-safe (I hope) list:

```
public class BlockingList<StateMessage> : IList<StateMessage>
{
    private List<StateMessage> _list = new List<StateMessage>();
    private object _sync = new object();


    public void Add(StateMessage item)
    {
        lock (_sync)
            _list.Add(item);
    }

    public bool Remove(StateMessage item)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            return _list.Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (_sync)
            _list.Clear();
    }
}
```

So, if the first thread adds an element, but a second one calls the `Clear()` method at the same time, would it be thread-safe?

Comment: Yes, since they are first locking or waiting to lock `_sync`.

Comment: But to add a bit more to this - if you are implementing `IList<StateMessage>` there are loads more methods you need to implement, including `GetEnumerator()`, `Contains`, `Count` and `this[int index]`... etc. I assume you are aware of that and that the above code is just a _sample_ of your entire code.

Comment: @rbm,yes i know that it just a sample piece of code. I implements all methods at my code.

Comment: OK, cool. Unless you really need to implement your own thread-safe list, you can always use built-in types, such as `ConcurrentBag<T>`.

Comment: @rbm, i know about `ConcurrentBag` and others collections., but i want to Clear all items without while loop or so on,

Comment: @rbm, you can post an answer ,not only comments.

Comment: Note that _reading_ this list is still not thread safe, by default, without taking special care of it. Say what will happen if one threads enumerates over list while another writes? Nothing good obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code is thread-safe since the methods are first locking or waiting to lock the `_sync` object.

You could use `ConcurrengBag` if you don't want to write your own. While it does not have the `Clear` method, you could simply create a new instance of `ConcurrentBag` and replace the old one.

Comment: ,Thank you. I did not think about rebuilding instance ConcurrentBag!

Comment: BTW - the `clear` is a future request - check https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2338